# Can zipping multiple lists cause performance issue in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have multiple lists in python which I zip as shown below. My question is whether is this the best practice to do or is there any other effective way. Secondly, will there be any performance issue if I zip multiple lists as shown below?

```
biglist = zip(list1,list2,list3,list4,list5)
```

Comment: Are all those lists of consistent len? If not I'd suggest `zip_longest()`

Comment: How big are the lists? It helps if you give sample code with random contents. Also, are you just iterating over them (once), or else why do you need the zipped output?

Comment: @smci - Every list contains 5 data points.

Comment: @fear_matrix no. 5 lists with 5 data points will not cause a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you do with the result. If you iterate over it once, `itertools.izip` would use less memory.